# How can I make db_select recognize an empty field?

Tags: database

I am writing a `db_select` in D7 to get various user fields, including the URI's of user's avatars (if it exists).

My initial attempt looked this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('users', 'u', 'n.uid = u.uid');
$query->join('file_managed', 'f',
  'f.fid = u.picture OR u.picture = :null', array(':null' => 0));
$query->fields('f',array('uri'));
```

This *almost* do the job.  The only glitch is that if the user has no avatar, the field `uri` always contains the uri pointing to `f.fid` #1.  In that case, I want it be missing or empty.

As a workaround, I now execute two db_selects: First one for all users that have an avatar:

```
$query->join('file_managed', 'f', f.fid = u.picture);
```

Then one for all users without:

```
$query->join('file_managed', 'f', u.picture = :null', array(':null' => 0));
```

I then just concatenate the results. This produces the desired result, but is a bit clumsy.

I would like to do it with one db_select if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a left join on 'files_managed' table

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('users', 'u', 'n.uid = u.uid');
$query->leftjoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = u.picture');
$query->fields('f',array('uri'));
$query->fields('n',array('nid'));
$query = $query->execute();
dpm($query->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Does this work when both f.fid and u.picture are not set?

Comment: It should, u.picture is set as 0 as default value which will bring uri as NULL

Comment: Thanks! I need to read up on the subtle differences between `join` and `leftjoin`.

Comment: Inner vs Left http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join